# Access home network Linux server (samba and other services) behind operators NAT (no public IP4 address)

Tags: linux, nat, samba

this is my first question here...

- I have got home small Linux server with RAID1 disks and few services (samba, ssh, minidlna) serving Windows 10 machines
- Home network is connected to operator's network via DSL fw/router ZYXEL
- NO PUBLIC ADDRESS for the router, operator has the NAT

What are possibilities to connect from my another remote Windows 10 machine to my network to get all the services? I use applications like Adobe's Photoshop, Lightroom and want to access my data on my samba Linux server with mounts...

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well the “obvious” solution is a VPN connection. Not directly to your router, of course, but using some sort of middleman.

One concrete possibility is using [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com/). It mediates peer-to-peer VPN tunnels and supports NAT hole punching. It has a free tier, but you need to use “social login” (Google, Microsoft or GitHub).

Another possible solution (maybe) is [ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/), but I’m not familiar with the specifics. From a quick look it’s somewhat similar to Tailscale.

Or you could roll your own using a cheap Virtual Private Server. On this VPS you would install a VPN server of your choosing (WireGuard is great, but OpenVPN is also still a good choice). You would then set your Linux box to always maintain a connection to this VPN server. You could use whatever client (phone, laptop, ...) to access the VPN from remote locations.

If you’re feeling adventurous you could also experiment with Nebula (by Slack), but it’s more complicated to set up. You’d still require that VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Look at cloudflare's Argo tunnelling. That works a bit like a VPN to let you expose a port on an unroutable IP.

Answer (score 0):

Demand IPv6 addressing from your ISP, where there is effectively infinite IP addresses for everyone.

Being behind a NAT444 is not a good experience, bad performance and your IPv4 address might get confused for someone else.

Possibly your ISP does not allow "servers" anyway. Unfortunately the class of service that does may be more expensive than other solutions.